# Is there any way to increase the performance of the Windows 10 Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, performance, loops, cmd

I have been using the command prompt while testing my Lua scripts for a long time. Recently, I learned there are properties to change the theme and some other stuff of the command prompt, and I was wondering if there is a way of improving its performance. (while doing long loops for example)

I actually do a lot of long loops and it would really save me a lot of time if I could make it go faster.

Comment: Please clarify: What do you mean by "long loop"? Do you mean that your Lua script is producing a large amount of output to the console window? If that's what you mean, then the problem is only related to the console, and not to cmd.exe.

Comment: One way to make the _console_ go faster is to avoid creating a lot of output :-) You could, for example, redirect the output from your command to a file: `lua script.lua > output.txt`. Another way to improve console performance is to minimize the console window so that Windows doesn't have to redraw it all the time while all that output is gushing out from your command.

Comment: it's better to modify your script to use a better algorithm, or to avoid writing to screen

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can do any sort of configuration to import cmd utility. Why not use powershell on your windows.

PowerShell is more complicated than the traditional Command Prompt, but it’s also much more powerful. The Command Prompt is dramatically inferior to shells available for Linux and other Unix-like systems, but PowerShell competes favorably. In addition, most Command Prompt commands are usable in PowerShell, whether natively or through aliases.

Comment: The OP mentions running Lua scripts, which has nothing at all to do with either CMD or PowerShell or any shell at all. We can assume that the Lua interpreter is a Windows console application, and the OP is disappointed with the display performance of the Windows console (conhost.exe). It is pretty slow compared to terminal emulators on other platforms. It's certainly faster than anyone can read, but it slows down commands that write a lot of text to the screen.